# Does rails have a way to get timestamp for mysql query usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently doing the following:

```
  timestamp = Time.new.to_time.to_i.to_s
```

Is there a function in rails that does this for you?

Comment: Oi veh! Talk about missing the obvious. Just realized for the current timestamp I can just use mysql's own function `NOW()`

Comment: The question is why do you need a traditional timestamp column when Rails provides the magic columns `created_at` and `updated_at` as soon as you create these? Such columns are magically filled and updated by Rails as soon as they exist in the table (type `DATETIME`)...

Comment: to store other dates (expiration date, etc) which are pertinent to business logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is doing this for you!

```
Model.where("date=?", Time.now-5.days)
```

Will automaticly generate the stamp of `Time.now-5.days` you dont need to convert them! What you shouldnt do is sth. like

```
Model.where("date=#{var here}")
```

This is deprecated for security and usability reasons!

Comment: Well the existing code gives a timestamp of `2011-11-07 03:59:15` while using `Time.now` gives `2011-11-07 03:59:15 -0800` .. notice the -0800 which breaks the sql query

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the magic columns `created_at` and `updated_at` of type `DATETIME`. Rails will automagically update and fill these columns, no need to bother with these during inserts. If you have `TIMESTAMP` columns due to importing a legacy database, consider creating a migration converting to Rails magic. It integrates much better than handling such strange timestamp columns which MySQL tries to handle in a quite unpredictable manner, plus it benefits your database abstraction (it will be more agnostic).